# How to use find_by with multiple "like" conditon

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to find a record whose title include 'foo' or 'bar'.
For that I wrote like this:

```
Post.find_by('title like ? or title like ?', '%foo%', '%bar%')
```

This code works fine, but it's a bit redundant.
If it's a exact match I can use an array. Is there similar way with `like` condition?

Comment: Looks fine for me, why is this query _a bit redundant._ ?Also `like` it is not a condition, it is an expression.

Comment: @ironsand for like clause you need to write this separated by `or` otherwise you can use `REGEXP` like `Post.where("title REGEXP ?",'foo|bar')`

Answer (score 1):

When you pass in a string into an AR query like the above, ( `'title like ? or title like ?', '%foo%', '%bar%'` ) you are basically writing a SQL-ish query.

That being said, a way to achieve this is may lie in the use of the `similar to` keyword in SQL.

This will simplify the query, and remove the repeated use of `title like ?`.

An example of usage for your scenerio is:

```
Post.find_by('title similar to ?', '%(foo|bar)%')
```

Hope this helps.